# Jackson, deserialize string into date

Tags: json, jackson, resttemplate

I have the following JSON property:

```
"created_at":"2017-12-08T10:56:01.000Z"
```

I would like to deserialize the JSON document using `Jackson` into the following property:

```
@JsonProperty("created_at")
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
private java.util.Date createdAt;
```

but it fails with the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.example.domain.Product] and content type [application/json;charset=utf-8]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:986)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:969)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:717)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:671)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:587)
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is with the `pattern` part of `JsonFormat`.

Use `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"` instead of `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ"`.

`"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"` for `"2017-12-08T13:50:07.811+0000"`

`"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"` for `"2017-12-08T13:49:42.128Z"`